# Code compiles in Elm but not in Haskell

Tags: haskell, matrix, functional-programming, transpose, elm

Currently I am trying to learn Haskell, but I stumbled upon an error which I do not understand:

```
* Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]
  Expected type: [a]
    Actual type: [[a]]
* In the expression: (addL x acc [])
  In the first argument of `foldl', namely
    `(\ x acc -> (addL x acc []))'
```

As to what I was actually trying to do, is that I was trying to transpose a matrix (code provided below). And the weird part is that if I run the code in Elm (with little tweaks) it works perfectly fine. I would need some help as I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

Elm code:

```
trans matrix =
   List.foldl (\x acc -> addL x acc []) [] matrix

addL x matrix solution =
   case x of
     []   -> solution
     h::t -> case matrix of
               []     -> addL t matrix (solution++[[h]])
               h2::t2 -> addL t t2 (solution++[h2++[h]])
```

Haskell code:

```
trans matrix =
  foldl (\x acc -> (addL x acc [])) [] matrix

addL x matrix solution =
  case x of
    []  -> solution
    h:t -> case matrix of
              []    -> (addL t matrix (solution++[[h]]))
              h2:t2 -> (addL t t2 (solution++[h2++[h]]))
```

Comment: `foldl` takes as first parameter the accumulator, so probably `foldl (\acc x -> ...) ...`

Comment: All. Ways. Use. Type signatures!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The difference is the *semantics* of the `foldl` functions. In Elm the signature of [**`foldl`** [elm-doc]](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/List#foldl) function is:

```
foldl : (a -> b -> b) -> b -> List a -> b
```

Whereas in Haskell, the signature of [**`foldl`** [haskell-doc]](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldl) is:

```
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

So in Haskell, the accumulator is the first parameter, and the second is an element of the list. In Elm it is the opposite. So it should probably work with:

```
trans matrix =
  foldl (\acc x -> (addL x acc [])) [] matrix
```